# Geographical identification location (GeoLocation/GeoTag) in SVG

Tags: svg, geolocation, geotagging, gis, xml-formatting

I am wondering how to geotag SVG maps.

#### My search results

- Geotags are available in metadata formats such as [Exif](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/gps.html), [XMP](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/XMPSpecificationPart2.pdf) and [GeoTIFF](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/spec/geotiff2.5.html#2.5.3.1).
- There is even a geotag for [SMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoSMS) (based on ["geo:" URI](http://geouri.org/))
- But there is [no geotags in SVG standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/SVG/Element).
- And not found Exif/XMB/... in SVG ([ExifTool does not support SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool))
- Not found standard to encode GeoLocation within filename 
   (eg: *RockwoodRural_geo_50.167958_-97.133185.svg*)
- As [GeoLocation can be embedded in XHTML/HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging#HTML_pages), and SVG is also XML-based, thus use one of these tricks:

  ```
  <meta name="ICBM" content="50.167958, -97.133185">

  <meta name="geo.position"  content="50.167958;-97.133185"\>
  <meta name="geo.placename" content="Rockwood Rural"\>
  <meta name="geo.region"    content="ca-mb"\>

  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
           xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
     <geo:Point>
        <geo:lat>55.701</geo:lat>
        <geo:long>12.552</geo:long>
     </geo:Point>
  </rdf:RDF>

  <span class="geo">
     <span class="latitude">50.167958</span>
     <span class="longitude">-97.133185</span>
  </span>
  ```

#### My questions

1. Does someone has already GeoTagged an SVG image?
2. What XML tag to use?
3. Should I create a specific SVG tag and propose an RFC?
4. What do you advice?

#### My specific usage

For information, I am developing on my spare time a website for commons-based maps peer production: [Lmap.org](http://lmap.org/vi/en_c/Welcome_en.html). I would like to embed the Geo-Location within the SVG code => The downloaded SVG maps will already contain all the Geo-Location data.

I think SVG GeoTagging could be interesting for maps and building representation, for instance:

- [Paris Ring Road](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:BP_de_Paris.svg)  (SVG in Public domain) 
   [image: Paris ring road]
- [Greater Vancouver Regional District by TastyCakes on English Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:GVRD_-_Belcarra.svg) (Own work) [CC-BY-3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0) 
   [image: Greater Vancouver Regional District]
- [Eiffel tower by Alexandre JABORSKA on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AEiffel_tower.svg) (Public domain) 
   [image: Eiffel tower]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most advanced reference I found is the [Dublin Core DCMI-box](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-box/).

#### 2000 version

The [2000's version](http://dublincore.org/documents/2000/07/28/dcmi-box/) was something such :

```
<Box name="Duchess copper mine">
    <northlimit>-21.3</northlimit>
    <eastlimit>139.9</eastlimit>
    <southlimit>-21.4</southlimit>
    <westlimit>139.8</westlimit>
    <uplimit>400</uplimit>
    <downlimit>-100</downlimit>
</Box>
```

[osgeo.org](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Geodata_Metadata_Requirements) cite the DClite4G scheme :

```
 <dct:spatial>
  <Box projection="EPSG:4326" name="Geographic">
    <northlimit>34.353</northlimit>
    <eastlimit>-96.223</eastlimit>
    <southlimit>28.229</southlimit>
    <westlimit>-108.44</westlimit>
  </Box>
</dct:spatial>
```

They also have a [list of RDF](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Geodata_Metadata_Requirements#RDF)

#### 2006 version

The [2006 Dublin Core DCMI-box](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-box/) values used with [their generator (click on DCMI-box)](http://www.dublincoregenerator.com/generator.html#openDCMIBox) suggest the XML syntax as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">

<dcterms:spatial xsi:type="dcterms:Box">
  name=france;northlimit=55;
  eastlimit=10;
  southlimit=44;
  westlimit=-5;
  projection=ESPXYZ;
</dcterms:spatial>

</metadata>
```

[image]

you can naturally change the units.