# How to geotags SVGs using D3js?

Tags: xml, svg, d3.js, geotagging

D3js is extensively used for cartography while there are also some recommended ways to geotags XML documents. I noticed the [Dublin Core DCMI-box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26821369/1974961).

[image]

It requires to add a bunch of xmlns things and geodata.

```
var svg_geotag = '<metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'
    +'xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"'
    +'xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">'
    +'<dcterms:spatial xsi:type="dcterms:Box">'
    +'name='+ITEM+';'
    +'northlimit='+NORTH+';'
    +'eastlimit='+EAST+';'
    +'southlimit='+SOUTH+';'
    +'westlimit='+WEST+';'
    +'projection='+ESPXYZ';'
    +'</dcterms:spatial></metadata>';
```

**But is there a recommended way to add such geotags to d3js maps ?**

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You'd just need to add the respective elements and attributes to the SVG, wouldn't you?

Comment: Hello @LarsKotthoff, nice to see you. As the structure is static and has no repetition, how would you proceed to add the whole `var svg_geotag` with efficiency ? pass it as a single string ? or a succession of `svg.append("element").attr("attrname", "value");` ?

Comment: Aside, I wonder if there is a common geotag syntaxe used by @mbostock & co.

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. I would just add it as a static string as it would be quite a lot of code otherwise.

Comment: If you were going to build it with d3, you could use the alternate version of the [selection.attr() function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#attr), passing an object with key-value pairs to set all the attributes at once.